# Universal Viewer 2.0.2 build process

Tags: iiif

Something has changed in the latest UniversalViewer (https://github.com/UniversalViewer/universalviewer)

Previously the build process would build all files into a `uv/build/uv-xx-xx-xx` directory. Which could then be moved as required and used something like so:

```
<div class="uv" style="min-width:750px; min-height:750px; height:100%; max-height:100%; margin:0 auto; background-color: #000"
    data-fullscreen="0"
    data-assetsequenceindex="0"
    data-assetindex="0"
    data-locale="en-GB:English,cy-GB:Welsh"
    data-uri="/<?php echo $partner; ?>/<?php echo $identifier; ?>/manifest"
    <?php echo $extra; ?>
></div>

<script type="text/javascript" id="embedUV" src="/packages/uv/build/uv-xx-xx/lib/embed.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately the build process appears to have changed but not been documented fully. Compiled js files now appear in the `src/` directory and a `.build/` directory.

If I use the whole `uv/` directory, there is an error that `uv.js` is missing.
If I use only the `uv/.build/` directory. Then the `embed.js` is missing.

What is the correct procedure after running `grunt build --dist` to now get the above php file working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running `grunt build` in UV3, you will nee to copy over the `./examples` directory and that should function similarly.

Comment: The examples directory does not include an embed.js either.

Comment: After running `grunt build`, `./examples/uv/.` should contain the "built UV" components necessary to run the application. These are copied from the `.build` directory. There is no `embed.js` file anymore. `uv.html` provides an example of how all of this works together: https://github.com/UniversalViewer/examples/blob/afbfc76fe2e0a65d9de003339fc31e4a958fa2b5/uv/uv.html

Comment: Thanks, this got me a step further although I started to run into other issues such as the dependency files not having the '.js' extension appended to them.
With this in mind I'm sticking with 2.0.2 for now.